# Charging with Stripe

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm having a bit of an issue getting the charging to work with Stripe. Composer wouldn't install so I've loaded it manually. Getting no `PHP` errors, and my token creation is working fine. I can't see any obvious mistakes or syntax errors, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

index.html code:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>


<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    token: function(token) {
        /* Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
         You can access the token ID with `token.id`
         Pass along various parameters you get from the token response
         and your form.*/
        var myData = {
                token: token.id,
                email: token.email,
                amount: 500,
                message: $("#message").val()
        };
        /* Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
           change the first parameter to your charge script*/
        $.post("charge2.php", myData,function (data) {
            // if you get some results back update results
            $(".results").html("Your charge was successful");
        }).fail(function () {
            // if things fail, tell us
            $(".results").html("I'm sorry something went wrong");
        })
    }
});
document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
        name: 'GUTIC',
        description: 'Join today!',
        amount: 500
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});


</script>
```

charge2.php

```
<?php echo // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
 // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
 require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("pk_test_DapJwVUCol6JDjJ4jsqEr6S7");

 // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
 // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
 $token = $_POST['token'];
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
     'amount' => 999,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'description' => 'Example charge',
     'source' => $token,

     print_r($_POST)


 ]);; ?>
```

Comment: could you clarify a little what the exact issue is? Are charges just not being created? If you look at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs do you see any errors or charge requests?

Comment: @karllekko yep - not been created. No errors there. Also no charge requests. Only v1 tokens

Comment: Do you see the request to charge2.php being made in your browser's developer tools? If you `print_r($_POST)` from your script what do you see?

Comment: I'm seeing '1Array ( )' when I place that and load the PHP file. I see in my developer tools that change2.php is being requested and returning a 500 error. No syntax errors as far as I can tell though...

Comment: oh, I just noticed — you're passing your public key to `setApiKey` in the PHP script. It should be your secret key(`sk_test_xxx`).

Comment: This was the issue - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the issue is that you are using your publishable key(`pk_test_xxx`) in the call to `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey` However, you should use your secret key(`sk_test_xxx`) here instead, as creating a charge requires a secret key to be used. You can get your keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

Using the wrong key should give you an API error with a 403 response code. You can see that in your Stripe [dashboard logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method[]=post&method[]=delete&direction[]=connect_in&direction[]=self). You may have to toggle between test and live mode(using the switch in the left navbar) to see the relevant request.

Also, in the code, the `print_r` statement is within the parameters of the `\Stripe\Charge::create` call which would also give you an error — instead, it should be outside, most likely just after the `setApiKey` line.